# Testing edittext getText method

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, android-testing

I have a class `UiUtils` with methods such as:

```
public static String getEditTextValue(final EditText editText) {
    if(editText == null) return null;
    final Editable text = editText.getText();
    if(text == null) return null;
    return text.toString();
}
```

Then I want to add unit testing to that class. I was creating a simple unit test but this is failing. I've done that:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UiUtilsTest {
    @Mock
    EditText editText;

    @Test
    public void getEditTextValue_ReturnsValueString() {
        final String value = "text";
        editText.setText(value);
        Assert.assertEquals(value, UiUtils.getEditTextValue(editText));
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm creating a mocked `EditText` then I `setText` and expect to get the same value. But for some reason the `editText.getText()` method always returns `null`. What is going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: Use `Espresso` to test `UI`. `getText` never returns null

Comment: How could I create that test with espresso? This is a static method so I'm not testing an activity nor fragment, so, how could I create an edittext with espresso to do that test?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UiUtilsTest {
    @Mock
    EditText editText;

    @Test
    public void getEditTextValue_ReturnsValueString() {
        final String value = "text";
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(editText).setText(value);
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(editText).getText();
        editText.setText(value);
        Assert.assertEquals(value, UiUtils.getEditTextValue(editText));
    }
}
```

Comment: When doing editText.setText I'm getting an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setText in android.widget.TextView not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.

Comment: I have solution of this issue but even after that get text will return null :O

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was running into the same problem, please try out this:

```
 @Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    when(rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_logout)).thenReturn(buttonLogout);
    when(rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_unlock)).thenReturn(buttonUnlock);
    when(rootView.findViewById(R.id.ScreenLock_PasswordTextField)).thenReturn(passwordField);

    when(passwordField.getText()).thenReturn(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("asd"));
    when(application.getPassword()).thenReturn("asd");

    sut = new ScreenLockPresenterImpl(application, rootView, screenLockListener,
            logoutButtonClickListener);
}


@Test
public void testOnClickWhenOk() {
    sut.onClick(null);

    verify(passwordField).getText();
    verify(screenLockListener).unLock();
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for:
**when(passwordField.getText()).thenReturn(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("asd"));**